# How create expiration for row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have a table `LoginControl` in a SQL Server database.

I want to automaticaly delete a property after 30 minutes from adding.

I have two properties (`LoginId` and `Token`) in the `LoginControl` table and I want to delete them both as one in a row.

I have just created a simple database with Visual Studio 2012 and access it via Entity Framework.

Is there any solution? Some settings in Visual Studio while I creating `*.edmx` file?

Comment: What business problem are you addressing with this proposed solution?

Comment: I want write simple method whitch control if user is loged. I want to create cookie property in user's browser and regular validate it with tables entry with this method. I want 30 minutes timer for both (cookie and table row). It is part of my shool Single Sign On project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how these kind of tasks are done - they are not implemented in SQL, but rather in the business logic of the application.

You should better:

1. add a timestamp field to both tables, storing the insertion time (you could even do that with a trigger)
2. validate the timestamps when doing queries on the affected tables, and discard "too old" records in the queries
3. create a periodic job for cleaning the DB every day or every hour that would clean the stale login records.

   - on the SQL server: many say this is the way to go. This uses the DB for what it is: taking care of data. Stale data needs to be deleted - form this aspect, the DB should be used for this.

     - it requires using the scheduling facilities of the DB,
     - code is not in one place, it requires more care to deal with releases, if the application code is only in the application, and not using DB features already
   - in the application: I'd prefer this, because this way all the logic is in one place. But this is my personal view, that has clear disadvantages too:

     - more application code,
     - it requires a scheduling logic in the application, which if previously not present, has to be added and most importantly, taken care of in the long run

So a lot regarding the decision on where to put the clean/up logic on the existing nature of the application - and of course the available features.

Comment: so, there is no such a thing as "auto expiry"?

Comment: Creating the periodic job in the sql server seems like a better way than creating the job in a windows service or a task scheduled console application.

Comment: @Moulde While already having an app using a DB, nobody would consider having another component (win service, scheduled console app) to groom. I meant a periodic job as part of the application.

In my opinion, it would be best to build the cleanup logic into the application whose business logic it is part of, to keep thnigs at one place.

Considering a job in the SQL server - though this is not my personal preference - there are reasons to do so. It would mean better performance, not using the app server for something the DB should do, that is true - I just like logic to be in one place.